# array -> inverse array manually without library and check if it palindrome

Tags: arrays, c

When studying arrays I got a problem.
I'd appreciate if you help me to get output for this code.
I need to

- inverse array in new array
- compare both arrays to check whether input is a palindrome or not
- without using string.h library

```
# include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char pal[15],palcpy[15];
    int slen,i,j;
    printf("\t\tpalindrome checker :)\n\nplease input the word you need to check : ");
    scanf("%s", pal);
    slen = strlen(pal);
    
    
    for(i=slen ; i>=0 ; i--)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<=slen ; j++)
        {
            palcpy[j] = pal[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%s", pal);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take this as the perfect opportunity to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. Use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, to see what's happening and compare to what you expected to happen.

Comment: You have not actually clearly described any specific error or incorrect behaviour. Your code does not make any attempt to check for palidrome. The definition of palidrome is that the string and the reverse of the string are the same. Once you have reversed the string you just need to `strcmp` the two values.

Comment: You are copying `pal[slen]` to `palcpy[0]`. Guess what `pal[slen]` is going to be for any string? The NUL character. It means `palcpy` is always an empty string.

Comment: Please explain your reasoning for using two nested loops.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ Start with a HelloWorld. Extend to read a string and echo. Extend to copy the string to a second array. Modifyx to echo from copy. Extend to verify that original and copy are identical. Modify to copy in reverse.

Comment: Just a sidenote: `string.h` is a header holding declarations for part of the standard C library. It is not a library itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ ( and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) ) I recommend:

- Start with a HelloWorld, test
- Extend to read a string and echo, test
- Extend to copy the string to a second array, test
- Modify to echo from copy, test
- Extend to verify that original and copy are identical, test
- Modify to copy in reverse, test